# Keras (tf backend) memory allocation problems

Tags: tensorflow, memory-management, keras

I am using Keras with Tensorflow backend.
I am facing a batch size limitation due to high memory usage

My data is composed of 4 1D signals treated with a sample size of 801 for each channel. Global sample size is 3204

Input data:
4 channels of N 1D signals of length 7003
Input generated by applying a sliding window on 1D signals
Give input data shape (N*6203, 801, 4)

N is the number of signals used to build one batch

```
My Model:
Input     801 x 4
Conv2D     5  x 1, 20 channels
MaxPooling 2  x 1
Conv2D     5  x 1, 20 channels
MaxPooling 2  x 1
Conv2D     5  x 1, 20 channels
MaxPooling 2  x 1
Conv2D     5  x 1, 20 channels
Flatten
Dense      2000
Dense      5

With my GPU (Quadro K6000, 12189 MiB) i can fit only N=2 without warning
With N=3 I get a ran out of memory warning
With N=4 I get a ran out of memory error
```

It sound like batch_size is limitated by the space used by all tensors.

```
Input      801 x 4 x 1
Conv       797 x 4 x 20
MaxPooling 398 x 4 x 20
Conv       394 x 4 x 20
MaxPooling 197 x 4 x 20
Conv       193 x 4 x 20
MaxPooling 96  x 4 x 20
Conv       92  x 4 x 20
Dense      2000
Dense      5
```

With a 1D signal of 7001 with 4 channels -> 6201 samples

```
Total = N*4224 MiB.
N=2 -> 8448 MiB fit in GPU
N=3 -> 12672 MiB work but warning: failed to allocate 1.10 GiB then 3.00 GiB
N=4 -> 16896 MiB fail, only one message: failed to allocate 5.89 GiB
```

Does it work like that ? Is there any way to reduce the memory usage ?
To give a time estimation: 34 batch run in 40s and I got N total = 10^6

Thank you for your help :)

Example with python2.7: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1N7K_bxblC97FejozL4g7J_rl6-b9ScCn

Comment: So one your sample with N=1 is 20 millions floats? And then you convolve it and get 20 times more? And you are wondering for why they need to be put into GPUs RAM? The first idea is to cut somehow your first sliding window, multiplying your data 800x (or 6200x?)...

Comment: Indeed the sliding window do x800, the memory consumption is indeed huge, but i was wondering is there aren't any memory optimization method like only allocating the two biggest tensors (N *  2262 MiB) and doing computations with just these two tensors.The window size is fixed and my tutor told me to not change it.

Comment: Theoretically maybe, then people will point at ways to unload data during computation. Generally such multiplications are strange. Don't you get data like [a, b, c, ...], then [b, c, d, ...], [c, d, e, ...]...? I.e. each of 800 copies differs very slightly. Another idea, if you need to process all your data with big N - to add part cutting step (net = net[partNum * 1000 : (partNum + 1) * 1000, :, :, :]) and to process data in several passes